# nsys says "please use the qdrep file instead" - huh?

Tags: cuda, nsight-systems

I'm using NVIDIA Nsight Systems version 2019.5.2.16-b54ef97 with CUDA 10.2. I'm running:

```
nsys profile my_app --some --args=here
```

so, a plain-vanilla profiling with no funny business. And yet, I get, at the bottom of the output:

```
... etc. etc. ...
Saving report to file "/some/where/report1.qdrep"
Report file saved.
Please discard the qdstrm file and use the qdrep file instead.

Removed /some/where/report1.qdstrm as it was successfully imported.
Please use the qdrep file instead.
```

Why am I being told to discard files and use other files instead? Especially given how, eventually, only a single file is generated (a `.qdrep` file)?

I'm guessing some internal conversion utility is run, and the message is not really intended for me - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It is just a logging, which is a little confusing though, and later it removes the *.qdstrm file for you automatically.